# GLSL Point Light Problems

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl, lighting

When I render my 3d scene using a point light shader, I run into a few problems.  The light seems to rotate with the camera, the light also behaves like a directional light instead of a point light.  I was following this tutorial for glsl point lights.
[GLSL Core Tutorial – Point Lights](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-core-tutorial/point-lights/)

My Vertex Shader:

```
#version 150 core

in vec4 in_Position;
in vec4 in_Color;
in vec2 in_TextureCoord;
in vec3 in_Normal;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat3 normal;

out Data {
    vec3 normal;
    vec3 eye;
    vec3 lightDir;
    vec2 st;
} Out;

void main(void) {
    vec4 pos = view * model * in_Position;
    vec3 norm = normal * in_Normal;
    //Light Position
    vec4 l_pos = view * model * vec4(0,1,0,1);

    Out.normal = norm;
    Out.lightDir = vec3(l_pos - pos);
    Out.st = in_TextureCoord;
    Out.eye = vec3(-pos);
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * in_Position;
}
```

My Fragment Shader:

```
#version 150 core

uniform sampler2D texture_diffuse;

in Data {
    vec3 normal;
    vec3 eye;
    vec3 lightDir;
    vec2 st;
} DataIn;

out vec4 out_Color;

void main(void) {
    vec4 diffuse = texture(texture_diffuse, DataIn.st).rgba;
    vec4 spec = vec4(0.0);
    vec4 specular = vec4(0.2,0.2,0.2,1);
    vec4 ambient = vec4(0.2,0.2,0.2,1);

    float shininess = 100;

    vec3 n = normalize(DataIn.normal);
    vec3 l = normalize(DataIn.lightDir);
    vec3 e = normalize(DataIn.eye);

    float intensity = max(dot(n,l), 0.0);
    if (intensity > 0.0) {
        vec3 h = normalize(l + e);
        float intSpec = max(dot(h,n), 0.0);
        spec = specular * pow(intSpec, shininess);
    }
    out_Color = max(intensity * diffuse + spec, ambient);
}
```

Picture of the problem:

[image: Shader Issue]

Comment: Usually you define the light position in world space so you would only multiply it by the view matrix, not the model matrix. That may be why it appears to move with the camera.

Comment: @user3256930 that might explain why it's behaving sort of like a directional light, but still doesn't explain why it's rotating with the camera.